# MySQL breaking column values by comma

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am querying MySQL database (`fintech_16`) through Python (pymysql) to get UNIQUE values of a column (`Trend`). When I ran the following query:

```
cursor.execute ("SELECT DISTINCT `Trend` FROM `fintech_16` ")
cursor.fetchall()
```

I got the following result:

```
((u'Investments',),
 (u'Expansion',),
 (u'New Products',),
 (u'Collaboration',),
 (u'New Products,Investments',),
 (u'New Products,Expansion',),
 (u'Expansion,Investments',),
 (u'New Products,Collaboration',),
 (u'Regulations',),
 (u'Investments,New Products',),
 (u'Investments,Expansion',),
 (u'Collaboration,Investments',),
 (u'Expansion,New Products',),
 (u'Collaboration,New Products',))
```

Now. since some of the ids had more than one trend, the DB is counting them as a separate trend.

How should I tweak my query to get only the 5 trends *(Investments, Expansion, New Products, Collaboration, Regulations)* along with their counts?

Though these are only 5, I can use the `LIKE %Investments%` to get the count manually, but I want the code/query to do it.

TIA

Comment: What is your expected output. Edit and Add it to your question above.

Comment: GIGO. See normalisation.

Answer (score -1):

First approach is to use [SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) data type to define exact values, you have 5 - ['New Products', 'Investments', 'Expansion'...].

Then you could use FIND_IN_SET function to count values you need:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `fintech_16` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('New Products', `Trend`) > 0;
```